# how can I return column that i already deleted in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, return, drop

Using `df.drop()` I removed the "ID" column from the `df`, and now I want to return that column.

```py
df.drop('ID', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
# shows me df without ID column
```

What method should I use?

Comment: In like this situation i save that column in an variable, and drop original column.

Comment: You cannot get back column dropped by `inplace=True`.

Answer (score 0):

found that all you need to do is to reload again the first command of the import of the df :)